# How to insert yesterday's date in googlesheet

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to enter yesterday's date in certain cells in googlesheet, and not have it autoupdate. e.g., `TODAY()` and `NOW()` autoupdate. I know I can use `Ctrl+;` to get today's date, and that remains static. I need the equivalent for yesterday's date.

Googling hasn't turned up anything yet, and neither has the googlesheet docs.

Thanks for any help.
David

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: Could you enter today's date in a different cell, and then use a formula in the desired cell to subtract one day?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

- `TODAY()-1` or `NOW()-1`

Then copy > paste as values only

The above works because Google Sheets dates are serial numbers where the unit is 1 day.

You could create a macro that does the above which could be called by using a keyboard shortcut. For details about how to create a macro please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros

Answer (score 1):

They this:

```
function YESTERDAY() {
  return new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

=TEXT(TODAY( )-1, “00000”) should work

Comment: For me that produced "44263."